# Bundler does not load automatically (No bundle URL present error)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

After updating my React Native app to the latest version up to date (`0.60.4`), launching my app using `react-native run-ios` would result in my application starting without a Metro Bundler.

The application would then display the following error:
[image]

In order for my application to function properly, I need to start the Metro Bundler using `npm start` and then run `react-native run-ios`.

Although this is a workaround, previously I did not have this issue and simply running `react-native run-ios` would start the Metro Bundler automatically. How can I resolve this?

**EDIT:** My `NSAppTransportSecurity` from `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: which version of react-native-cli are you using?

Comment: @Federkun my react-native-cli version is `2.0.1`, I believe this is also the latest one.

Comment: before anything, could you try to delete the `ios/build` folder, make sure that every :8081 process is killed, and try again? can you also share what `NSAppTransportSecurity` values you have in your Info.plist?

Comment: @Federkun I have tried deleting the `build` folder and killing all :8081 processes using `kill $(lsof -t -i:8081);`. Still no success. I have updated my post to include all `NSAppTransportSecurity` values I have.

Comment: can you try to include `<key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key><true/>`?

Comment: @Federkun I just tried it. Still no success :(

Comment: I'm assuming that once you run `react-native run-ios`, the bundle start fine ( app can't just reach it ). Can you confirm it running `lsof -i :8081` after `run-ios`?

Comment: @Federkun That's the problem. The Metro bundler never launches. It launches neither in the same terminal nor in a separate one. React Native directly boots up the app without a metro bundler being loaded. I can confirm I tried to kill all processes using port 8081 several times, yes.

Comment: Do you have this issue even when trying to `run-ios` on the react-native template ( immediatly after `react-native init`? )

Comment: @Federkun No, this issue persists only on my main project. A newly generated one would work just fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess this issue is common when upgrading existing projects to React Native `v0.60.+`.

For anyone encountering this issue on Mac:

1. Open `Xcode` and locate `Build Phases` under your project.
2. Tap on `Editor` -> `Add Build Phase` -> `Add Run Script Build Phase`.
   [image]
3. Tap on the newly generated `Run Script` on the bottom of `Build Phases` tab.
4. Paste the following code:

```
export RCT_METRO_PORT="${RCT_METRO_PORT:=8081}"
echo "export RCT_METRO_PORT=${RCT_METRO_PORT}" > "${SRCROOT}/../node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env"
if [ -z "${RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER+xxx}" ] ; then
if nc -w 5 -z localhost ${RCT_METRO_PORT} ; then
if ! curl -s "http://localhost:${RCT_METRO_PORT}/status" | grep -q "packager-status:running" ; then
echo "Port ${RCT_METRO_PORT} already in use, packager is either not running or not running correctly"
exit 2
fi
else
open "$SRCROOT/../node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command" || echo "Can't start packager automatically"
fi
fi
```

5. Launch your project through `Xcode`. `Metro Bundler` should now automatically start.
6. After saving your changes, the next time you run `react-native run-ios` in Terminal, `Metro Bundler` will automatically start and the `No bundle URL present` error will no longer persist.

Comment: After struggling with this issue for days, this solution worked for me. Thank you! (For anyone wondering why this works, here's a thread with a bit more context on the solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25585)

Answer (score 4):

What work for me is to

1. Click on the App Target
2. Look for Bundle React Native code and images
3. Uncheck run script for install builds only
4. Uncheck run script based on dependency analysis.

[image]

Comment: Why is that screenshot of the answer?

Comment: this answer works for me

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps. I have also faced this issue and this was solved by :

1. Update your react native cli to the latest version.
2. If using androidX then please use jetifier and npx.
3. Update your package JSON in which development dependencies look like this

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
   "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
   "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
   "jest": "^24.7.1",
   "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
   "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
},
```

There is a walk around to start the metro bundler.
Use : `npm start --reset cache` This will start your metro bundler.

Comment: I have followed all your steps and upgraded all my dependencies. I am still encountering this issue.